# How to tell when file has finished downloading and ready to use?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I am downloading a file (.json) from my own web service and whe it is finished downloading I need the contents to be 'unpacked' into a local SQLlite database.

I understannd that NSURLConnection downloads the file asynchronously on another thread to keep the main thread open.  The problem is that when the file download has started, the main thread, obviously, carries on doing what it's doing - in this case trying to load the contents of the file into the database.  By the time this happens the file either does not yet exist OR exists but is not yet complete.

How do I run the method that input the contents of the file into the database only AFTER the file is actually fully downloaded and ready to use?

```
-(void)downloadTheFileFrom:(NSString*)url withToken:(NSString*)token
{   
    NSString *conURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", apiURL, url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:conURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:(@"content-type")];
    [request addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:(@"X-TOKEN")];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [conn scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [conn start];
    [self saveJsonToDatabase];
}
```

Method that saves the file to the database:

```
-(void)saveJsonToDatabase
{
    NSString *jsonFileToSave = @"drug.json";
    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    NSError *jsonError = nil;

    NSString *jsonFile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/content/formulary/files/%@", jsonFileToSave]];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonFile];
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&jsonError];

    NSString *formularyTable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"formulary_%@", [jsonFileToSave stringByDeletingPathExtension]];

    FormularyDBManager *formularyDBManagerInstance = [FormularyDBManager new];
    [formularyDBManagerInstance insertInto:formularyTable arrayOfDicts:jsonArray];
}
```

Delegate methods for NSURLConnection:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSString *apiUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[response URL]];
    NSArray *pathComponents = [apiUrl pathComponents];
    NSString *areaFolder = [pathComponents objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *fileName = [response suggestedFilename];
    NSString *fileType = [fileName pathExtension];

    NSString *docsfolderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *folderPath = [docsfolderPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/content/%@/%@", areaFolder, contentType]];

    BOOL isDir;
    NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:folderPath isDirectory:&isDir])
        if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
            NSLog(@"FileDownloader - connection - Error: Create folder failed %@", folderPath);

    NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    connection.file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];

    _currentFile = fileName;
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [connection.file writeData:data];
}
-(NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(FileURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    [connection.file closeFile]; 
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"GetData - connection - error - %@", error);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick with NSURLSession and NSURLSessionDownloadTask since NSURLConnection is deprecated.

A NSURLSessionDownloadTask can answer in a block or to a delegate, lets stick to the block variant.

```
// Your request
NSString *conURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", apiURL, url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:conURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:(@"content-type")];
[request addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:(@"X-TOKEN")];    

// Create a simple Session
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
// Create the downloadTask
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable tempLocation, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    // this block will be called on a async thread when the task is finished.
    // if no error occurred and we got a path lets store the data.
    if (!error && tempLocation) {
        // I pass the location to your function, so it can read the file.
        [self saveJsonToDatabase:tempLocation];
    }
}];
[downloadTask resume];  // don't forget to start the task.
```

The task calls its block when it is finished or failed. The file at tempLocation is only temporary and will be delete afterwards, if you want to keep it you need to move it to a different path.

For more details you can read the apple docs for using [NSURLSession + Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html)

Comment: This looks like it could fit what I'm looking for.  Can I define where the files will be saved?  I use this class to save a whole bunch of files, it's only a couple that I have to 'interecpt' and put their contents into the database.

Comment: You can move the files to a passed location. `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:tempLocation toPath:passedFilePath error:nil];` should do the trick.

Comment: After re-writing my code and adding in the suggested changes this are now working as intended. Also, this method seems a lot simply than having load of delegate methods to worry about too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use NSURLSessionDownloadTask it will be easier to handle since it is a completion block method. When it's done downloading the code in the block will be executed. Plus NSURLConnection has been deprecated.